# setting up auth0-authorization-extension-api

Tags: python, python-2.7, jwt, auth0, flash-message

I want to implement authorization mechanism to my python flask application. I want o manipulate authorization of groups, users and etc... in my application.

After reading through these pages about how to setup authorization through extension

1-https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/grant/authorization-code

2-https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/python#add-api-authorization

I added this decorator which is shown in the second link above (interesting thing is that I realized 2nd links decorator has the same decorator names with the [00-Starter-Seed](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-python-web-app/tree/master/00-Starter-Seed) app. So 2nd links decorator does authorization and authentication at the same time ?

`def requires_auth(f):
     ...
     ..
     .`

But when I tried to work that decorator, I am getting this error

```
{
  "code": "Error decoding token headers.", 
  "description": "Invalid header. Use an RS256 signed JWT Access Token"
}
```

I doubted from maybe I understand the concept of implementing authorization in Auht0 wrong. So, what I understand from it is

1 - check needs to be made to determine whether the incoming request contains valid authorization information (jwt)

2- get `access_token` and use it in decorator

3-call the api to manipulate groups, users, etc, ... (things I want to do through api) OR use it as function decorator to make use that function only be called by admin

what is the point I am not seeing or understanding wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work. The outline that I followed are

1. created authorization extension
2. configured authorization extension API
3. grand access to auth0-authz(non-interactive client)
4. in our web app ask created another token for auth0-authz(non-interactive client) to consume API
5. verified token over urllib.urlopen("https://"+AUTH0_DOMAIN+"/.well-known/jwks.json")
6. then made a successful API call with new token

Comment: Did you manage to get your custom claims on the accessToken ? after setting up your custom rule ?

Comment: I didn't need a custom rule in that project. I can't say something about that but with the way I described above I can add groups to the accessToken. I was using email verify rule or something like that. I think you can do that.